# SAS column input skipping lines

Tags: testing, sas

I was looking at the SAS base exam questions and I came across this particular one:

```
data test;
input employee_name $ 1-4; 
if employee_name = ‘Ruth’ then input idnum 10-11; 
else input age 7-8; 
datalines;
Ruth 39 11
Jose 32 22
Sue  30 33
John 40 44
;
run;
```

At first I thought the IDNum when the employee name is "Ruth" would be 11, but it seems it skips the Ruth row and jumps down to the second row, and inputs 22 instead. And why is Sue's age 40 instead of 30? Can someone explain why this is? Thank you.

Here is the result:

```
Name  IDnum  Age
Ruth  22
Sue          40
```

Comment: The results you list are NOT what you get if you run the code you posted. In fact the code you posted cannot run since it is using "smart quotes" instead of real quotes around the string literal.

Comment: use https://sasensei.com - answers come with explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a trailing `@` or `@@` at the end of an input statement, any subsequent input statements in the same data step will skip the rest of the current line start reading from the beginning of the next line.